# Unable to add if statement in react

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am finding difficult in adding if statement inside React. It is showing compilation error when I add if statement. Below is my code.

```
 {parametersSearchResults.length > 0 && [
            <ButtonWithMargin
              key="filter"
              label="Filter"
              id="filter"
              icon={
                this.state.filterMegaDropdownOpen ? (
                  <ArrowDropUp />
                ) : (
                  <ArrowDropDown />
                )
              }
              name={
                this.state.filterMegaDropdownOpen
                  ? 'filterExpanded'
                  : 'filterCollapsed'
              }
              iconOnRight
              onClick={this.toggleFilterMegaDropdown}
              width="80"
            />,
            <Button
              key="edit"
              label="Edit Parameters"
              icon={<Edit />}
              onClick={openEditParametersModal}
              disabled={selectedIndexes.length === 0}
            />,
            <SelectWithMargin
              instanceId="storeFilter"
              Value={{ label: 'Current', value: true }}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder="Store"
            />,
        ]}
```

I want to display SelectwithMargin storeFilter only when isDrodpownShown is true. So I tried to add the if condition as below.

```
{isDropDownShown && (
              <SelectWithMargin
              instanceId="storeFilter"
              Value={{ label: 'Current', value: true }}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder="Store"
            />
            )}
```

Above code throwing syntex error near &&. May I know what is the right way to add if statement in react component. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
getDropDown = (isDropDownShown) => {
   if(isDropDownShown){
       return (<SelectWithMargin
              instanceId="storeFilter"
              Value={{ label: 'Current', value: true }}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder="Store"
            />);
   }else{
     return (<div></div>);
   }
}


{ this.getDropDown(isDropDownShown) }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. This is not working. Again I am getting syntex error.

Comment: Updated my answer. try this one. @Niranjan